Installed Exe is showing different culture than debug/portable exe in WPF
Installed Exe is showing different culture than debug/portable exe in WPF

Above picture is the amount input of Debug exe in nl-NL culture (Netherland) I have added property currentculture because my Region is netherland.
But for Setup installed exe on same computer it is showing en-GB format.

What could be the reason?
Code:
private void CultureSettings()
{
    var cult = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
    if (ApplicationContext.Instance.OverideDateTimeFormat)
        cult = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    cult = (CultureInfo)cult.Clone();
    cult.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = cult.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
    cult.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = cult.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator;
    Culture = cult;
}

I have tried with portable exe and setup exe. both are showing different culture in WPF. I tried with CurrentCulture, invariantCulture.

What is Culture? To change the culture, we usually set CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture.

Does this answer your question? Setting Culture (en-IN) globally in WPF application

cult = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
I am taking the current culture of the region, it works fine when I debug it and take nl-NL culture.
However, When I create setup exe after publishing, it is showing en-GB.
Because, I need customization in the culture, I cannot select nl-NL direrctly.
like  cult = CultureInfo ("nl-NL");

So your app can change culture info? Or do you mean it can be used on computers with different cultures, so you need this to work with correct culture? If that is the case then maybe check your PC's culture and see if you have keyboard set to something else?

Current culture picks the culture of the system. It is fine on Debug mode and pick nl-NL. but for installed setup exe, Current Culture is picking en-US. I have tried multiple PCs but the issue remains unchanged. Please check the referenced code.
